# Reputation block layout after earning new privilege

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, privileges, activity

On the mobile web after new privilege is earned, reputation block contains some design issues:

- no margins
- poor text color inside bar

> [image: new privilege]

By tapping on "track the next one" link, page have been refreshed:

- no margins
- empty block in the middle
- obscure content

> [image: rep list]

Only after manual refreshing, page looks fine again:

> [image: stable]

It is hard to reproduce because you need to earn next privilege which takes a lot of time. But I believe it's no too hard for developers :)

Comment: You can probably repro just by joining a new site with association bonus.

Comment: @NathanTuggy that's no need for me. I already know about this bug. :)